# CHECKSUM(NEWID()) negative values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to update records in the `Auftrag` table with random int values

```
UPDATE Auftrag SET Dauer = ((CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 10)+0.5), Anfahrt = ((CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 70)+1), Beschreibung= 'Auto filled' WHERE Dauer IS NULL AND MitID IS NOT NULL
```

But why I also get negative values at `Dauer` and `Anfahrt` and how can I fix that?

Comment: because the `CHECKSUM` function can return negative values

Comment: @Lamak and how to avoid this?

Comment: using the `ABS` function

Comment: Wrap it in `ABS()`.

Comment: perhaps you may surround `CHECKSUM()` with `ABS()` function

Comment: @jofri . . . What are you really trying to do?

Comment: `ABS` works thanks :) @Gordon Linoff I need to update parts of a table with random int values first I tried `convert(int,rand()*365)` but this gave me the same value every time ^^

Comment: The odds are astronomical, but abs() would increase the risk of collision.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I don't think collision is a concern if they're limiting the range to 365 values (unless the table has < 365 rows). Maybe the OP can clarify if they want random, unique, or both.

Comment: `rand()` would never work across a set because it is one of the built-in function that is evaluated once per reference, not once per row. `newid()` works because it is the opposite.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Very astute observation regarding the rows.  However, I was surprised how easy it is to create collision using ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) .https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=078ed4de8db81726c7f63f48b5f01857

Answer (score 0):

You could return absolute value of `checksum(...)` using `abs()` function:

```
UPDATE Auftrag SET 
  Dauer = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 10 + 0.5, 
  Anfahrt = ABS(((CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 70 + 1, 
  Beschreibung= 'Auto filled'
WHERE 
  Dauer IS NULL 
  AND MitID IS NOT NULL
```

I've removed unnecessary parentheses, because order of operations takes care of that here.

Answer (score 0):

I usually wrap the function in `rand()`:

```
UPDATE Auftrag
    SET Dauer = floor(rand(checksum(newid())) * 10) + 0.5,
        Anfahrt = floor(rand(checksum(newid())) * 70) + 1,
        Beschreibung= 'Auto filled'
    WHERE Dauer IS NULL AND MitID IS NOT NULL;
```